# How does defining function variables before { and after function declaration work?

Tags: c, coding-style, standards

I have been looking at some documentation for my C projects and came across a peculiar type of function declaration. Here is an example:

```
function_name(arg1, arg2)
      int arg1;
      char *arg2
{
 //function code
....
```

How does this differ from normal:

```
function_name(int arg1, char *arg2){
```

And witch one is better to use at certain cituations?

Comment: The former isn't standard C. You were probably reading a book from the 1950s. Time to update your library? :-)

Comment: Urk. That's a so-called old-style function definition. You don't want to know about it.

Comment: It is K & R format of function definition, it is not approved by the standard.

Comment: @AlokSave I found an example of it where apple is using it : http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-433.1/sysctl.tproj/pathconf.c

Comment: @PovilasSid - just cause apple does something doesn't make it right.